# Why does the partial application `foldr id` typecheck?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference, fold, partial-application

In Haskell, I don’t understand why the partial application `foldr id` typechecks.

Relevant types are

```hs
> :t foldr id
foldr id :: a -> [a -> a] -> a

> :t foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b

> :t id
id :: a -> a
```

The first argument of `foldr` is `(a->b->b)`. In contrast the type of `id` is `a->a`. They shouldn’t be compatible.

Comment: `:t id :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a)` might be instructive.

Comment: @ChadGilbert thanks for the edit. FYI you can write `<!-- language-all: haskell -->` just once.

Answer (score 11):

Because `a -> b -> b` is actually `a -> (b -> b)`.

Since `id :: a -> a`, this unifies `a` with `b -> b` and so we get, with type variables consistently renamed for uniqueness,

```
foldr :: (a -> (b -> b)) -> b -> [  a   ] -> b
id    ::  c ->    c
-----------------------------------------------   |-  a ~ c ,  c ~ b -> b
foldr       id           :: b -> [  c   ] -> b
foldr       id           :: b -> [b -> b] -> b
```

That's all.

So what does it do?

```
foldr f z [x, y, ..., n]  =  f x (f y (... (f n z)...))
                          =  x `f` y `f` ...  n `f` z     -- infixr _ `f`

foldr id z [x, y,  ...,    n] =
    = id x (id y ( ... (id n        z )...))
    =    x (   y ( ... (   n ( id   z))...))
    = (  x .   y .  ...  . n . id ) z
    = foldr  (.)  id  [x,y,...,n]   z
```

Thus `foldr id = foldr ($) = flip (foldr (.) id)` which is quite nice to have. The functions held in the list all stack up, because the output and input types match.